# How can I print out the name of the button when I click the button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am using kivy and I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7.

I want to print out the name of each button when I press each button.
However, only the name of the last button is printed.

Below is the Python code

```
import kivy
    
kivy.require('2.0.0')
    
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

import os

Window.clearcolor = (.6, 1, .8, 1)
Window.size = (563, 1001)
Window.top, Window.left = 30, 800
    
path_list = ["music1","music2","music3"]

music = ""

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global music
        gl = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
    
        for music in path_list:
            bt = Button(text=music, size_hint_y=None, height=50)
            gl.add_widget(bt)
            bt.bind(on_press=self.music_f)
        sv = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1))
        sv.add_widget(gl)
        return sv

    def music_f(self,name):
        global music
        name = music
        print("pray "+str(name))
    
TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad design:

You use a `music` variable which will take the last value from the path_list due to the `for loop`, then you use that value to assign it to the `name`, this has no logic... Once the button is created with the `text=music`, you already have the value assign to the that button. As you bind `on_press` with music_f, the `name` should be the button, I would change that to `button`.
In `music_f` you can access the name by calling button.text

```
    def music_f(self,button):
        print("pray "+str(button.text))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know exactly what" .text" does :( , but your code has really helped a lot. Thank you so much again. ;p

Comment: `.text` hold the `text` value you initialized the object `Button(text=music, size_hint_y=None, height=50)`

Comment: Thank you. You've been a great help to me :)